# How can I get the list of values from a snowflake table in Year to date format

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table in snowflake which has the following format

| Year | Month | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 03 | a |
| 2021 | 03 | b |
| 2021 | 03 | c |
| 2021 | 04 | b |
| 2021 | 04 | c |
| 2021 | 04 | d |
| 2021 | 04 | f |

And I want to get the YTD count and the comma separated list of sales(ytd)
So the output will be like

| Year | Month | Count | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 03 | 3 | a,b,c |
| 2021 | 04 | 7 | a,b,c,d,f |

I can get the YTD count but can't seem to figure out a way to get the list of sales. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Try the LISTAGG function

Comment: Yeah, with listagg I can get the comma separated list but not in year to date format. I am sure there is some way to make it work with listagg but can't quiet find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t have anywhere to test this at the moment but something like this should work:

```
WITH CTE1 AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT YEAR, MONTH
    FROM TABLE1
)
SELECT T1.YEAR, T1.MONTH, 
COUNT(T2.SALES), LISTAGG(T2.SALES,’,’)
FROM CTE1 T1
INNER JOIN TABLE1 T2 ON T1.YEAR = T2.YEAR 
AND T1.MONTH >= T2.MONTH
GROUP BY T1.YEAR, T1.MONTH
```

Comment: This may be getting in the right direction, but this duplicates results. For example, month 4 has a count of 28 and sales of a,b,c,b,c,d,f,a,b,c,b,c,d,f,a,b,c,b,c,d,f,a,b,c,b,c,d,f.

Comment: Edited my answer which will hopefully solve this duplicates issue

Comment: It's getting closer. Month 4 correctly identifies a count of 7, but the sales are displayed as [a,b,c,b,c,d,f].

Comment: This works. Just give distinct clause in listagg and everything will be perfect. Thanks @NickW